# How to hide a div when the mouse is clicked outside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've a HTML div and I want to hide it whenever the user clicks on the page anywhere outside the div. Which clicking on which element should I trigger the onclick event??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the latest jQuery, v1.4.4:

```
$(<the div you want hidden>).click(false); //stop click event from bubbling up to the document
$(document).one('click', function(){
  $(<the div you want hidden>).hide(); //which will hide the div
});
```

In other words, this code says 'hide the div if you click on this page, unless you click on the div'.

Re: Toggle button

Then you'll have something like:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('div').toggle();
});
$('div').click(false);
$(document).click(function(){
  $('div').hide();
  //reset the toggle state, e.g.
  $('button').removeClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: I've a toggle button. Toggling on which will show and hide the div. Apart from that, I want to hide the div on clicking anywhere outside the div. I'm trying to create something like the twitter 'Sign In' button at twitter.com

Comment: Can you help me reset the toggle state. Suppose after I clicked on one element, when I click on another element, it should reset the toggle state to the initial one. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I marked the appropriate place to reset the toggle state.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(e) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); });
$(document.body).one("click", function() {
    $('#mydiv').hide();
});
```

Since `mydiv` is also a child of the `body` element, you don't want that when clicking on that element, the element would dissappear.
So when people click on the `mydiv`, you want it to stop bubbling up to the `body` element, that is why first you register a click event on your `mydiv`, and tell it to stop bubbling.

Comment: Uh, `.one()` takes in an `eventType` as an argument. Here, what event are you binding once?

Answer (score 0):

The BODY element.